# Vector of strings from CSV file not properly printing out

Tags: c++, csv

so I am trying to read create a 500 X 2 vector of strings and display them from a CSV file. I eventually want to convert these strings to doubles, but I would like to start by simply displaying and making sure the values in the vector are correct. I thought I had this right and my file is added to my directory. Here is the code:

```
int main() {

std::string line;
int r = 0;

std::ifstream file("Aerodynamics.csv");
std::vector <std::vector<std::string> > data;

if (getline(file, line)) {
    while (r < 500) {
        vector<string> row;
        stringstream iss(line);
        int c = 0;
        string val;

        while (c < 2 && getline(iss, val, ','))
        {
            row.push_back(val);
        }
        data.push_back(row);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++)
    {
        std::cout << data[i][j] << endl;
    }
} 
} //I will fix the formatting on this :)
```

When I run this code, my output just reads "finished with exit code 0".
I am not sure where I am going wrong, for I have tried to display things in the vector one at a time, but I still get no output. Thanks!

Comment: Might be a good idea to check that you can successfully open the file?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920106/ifstream-wont-open-file

Comment: once you fixed your current problem, this will be one of your next: When does this loop stop `while (r < 500)` ? Similar, you have a `c` that you use in a condition but never modify

Comment: @mathematician1975 Yeah it's weird because I am not using the file.open, just trying to do it with fstream. I've tried reading it in other ways, but the output I get is weird numbers that are not related to the one in the csv.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Basically I have 500 rows and 2 columns, so I am trying to fill in each cell in the vector by using r and c as my indices. So having r < 500 and c < 2 should accomplish this I think?

Comment: "by using r and c as my indices" i dont understand what you mean with that. Read your code carefully. `r` only appears in the condition of the loop. Same for `c`

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ah, I see what you mean, looks like I forgot to add r++ and c++ to end of my two while loops. I appreciate that, but I sadly still get no output.

Comment: Then you should use `row.size()` and `data.size()` instead. As mentioned, this isnt your current problem

Comment: Do you have a link to **Aerodynamics.csv** you can share on [openSUSE Paste](http://paste.opensuse.org/) or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Evolution . . .

First we will check the existing code, find the bugs, eliminate them and the we will refactor and optimize step by step.

The described error can only mean that you program could not open the file. Unfortunately, you did not check, if the file could be opened or not. So, getline will fail and the program will not enter the outer loop. WHich is on the other hand kind of good, becuase you did not increment the loop variable r. Same for the inner loop.

So the first fix looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    std::string line;
    int r = 0;

    std::ifstream file("r:\\Aerodynamics.csv");
    std::vector <std::vector<std::string> > data;

    while (r++ < 500 && getline(file, line)) {
        std::vector<std::string> row;
        std::stringstream iss(line);
        int c = 0;
        std::string val;

        while (c++ < 2 && std::getline(iss, val, ','))
        {
            row.push_back(val);
        }
        data.push_back(row);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << data[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, this will work, if the file is there, where we expect it. But the code is still rather C-Style and not so nice.

OK, then let's add an error check for "file open", use range based for loop at the end, abbreviate length type name and declaration with a using clause and add comments, so that we can read the code better.

This will result into:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using DataType = std::string;
using Columns = std::vector<DataType>;
using CSV = std::vector<Columns>;

int main() {

    std::string line{};
    unsigned int rowCounter{};

    // Open input file
    std::ifstream file("r:\\Aerodynamics.csv");

    // CHeck, if the file could be opened
    if (file)
    {
        // Here we will store the result
        CSV data{};

        // Do read maximum 500 rows
        while (rowCounter++ < 500 && getline(file, line)) {

            // Here we will store the row data
            std::vector<std::string> row{};

            // For easier handling, we put the just read line into a istringstream
            std::istringstream iss(line);

            int columnCounter{};
            DataType val{};

            // We want to read maxium 
            while (columnCounter++ < 2 && std::getline(iss, val, ','))
            {
                // Add next column to row vector
                row.push_back(val);
            }
            // Add a complete row to the result
            data.push_back(row);
        }

        // Print out the just read data
        for (const Columns& columns : data)
        {
            for (const DataType& d : columns)
            {
                std::cout << d << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
    {   // Inform user that we could not open the file
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open input file\n";
    }
}
```

So, this is now a complete working program, looks better than before and is readable. This is alread a piece of code with some quality.

Next step. We go now in the direction of "more modern C++". In C++ we use nowadays algorithms, iterators and dedicated functions for requested functionality.

First, we want to split a line with csv (comma separated values)

C++ has, since long, a build in and dedicated functionality, specifically designed for this purpose, to tokenize strings (split strings into tokens). And because such a simple dedicated function, designed for this purpose, is available, it simply should be used. There is no need for external libraries or complicated constructs. Simply use the `std::sregex_token_iterator`.

This is an iterator (like many other iterators), that iterates over tokens (sub-strings) of a string. So, what we want.

We can then use the `std::vector`s range constructor to write something simple like this:

```
std::vector tokens(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), delimiter, -1), {}));
```

So, we define a variable with the name "tokens" of type `std::vector` (with CTAD the type of the vector is automatically deduced). We use its range constructor and provide a begin and an end iterator. The begin iterator is the `std::sregex_token_iterator` and the end-iterator is its default-initialized counterpart.

To put such a vector into a 2D Vector, we use the outer vectors `emplace_back` function and do an inplace construction for the inner vector.

So you read the whole CSV-File with 2 statements

- a simple for loop
- a simple emplace back with the `std::sregex_token_iterator`

That is short and simple.

Additionally we introduce the `std::ostream_iterator` for data output. This will iterate over all available data in the container and call its inserter operator.

Then we have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

const std::regex delimiter{ "," };

// Short names for containers
using Columns = std::vector<std::string>;
using CSV = std::vector<Columns>;

int main() {

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream csvFile{ "r:\\Aerodynamics.csv" }; csvFile) {

        // Here we will store the read data
        CSV data{};

        // Read all lines of the source CSV file
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(csvFile, line); ) {

            // Split string into substrings and add result to our data vector
            data.emplace_back(Columns(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), delimiter, -1), {}));
        }

        // Show result to user
        for (const Columns& c : data) {
            std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
            std::cout << "\n";
        }

    } // This will call the destructor of csvFile and close the file
    else {
        // Inform user that we could not open the file
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open input file\n";
    }
}
```

Wow. This looks now already like C++ . . .

The next step is that we remember that C++ is an object oriented language. So, we can use classes (structs), to put data and methods, working on this data, into a encapsulated unit. Only the class should know, how to deal with its data. The out world should not care. Additionally, if we create a new type, we can also use the C++ ion/out stream facilities. With that it is possible to use our data type like any other build-in type.

Therefore, we will define a class struct "AerodynamicsValues", put the data coming from one line in the file in it and overwrite the extractor and inserter operator for easy reading and writing from / to streams. The functionality in the overwritten operators is the sam as shown above.

Object Oriented approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

const std::regex re{ "," };
struct AerodynamicsValues {

    // Our internal data for one row
    std::vector<std::string> aerodynamicsValues{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, AerodynamicsValues& ad) {

        // Read one complete line
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {

            // Copy data into our values
            ad.aerodynamicsValues.clear();
            std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(ad.aerodynamicsValues));
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Overwrite inserter 
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const AerodynamicsValues& ad) {
        std::copy(ad.aerodynamicsValues.begin(), ad.aerodynamicsValues.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, " "));
        return os;
    }
};


struct Aerodynamics {

    // All Aerodynamics data
    std::vector<AerodynamicsValues> data{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Aerodynamics& ad) {
        // Read all data
        ad.data.clear();
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<AerodynamicsValues>(is), {}, std::back_inserter(ad.data));
        return is;
    }

    // Overwrite inserter 
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Aerodynamics& ad) {
        std::copy(ad.data.begin(), ad.data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<AerodynamicsValues>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream csvFile{ "r:\\Aerodynamics.csv" }; csvFile) {

        Aerodynamics ad{};

        // Read all values from CSV file
        csvFile >> ad;

        // Show read data to user
        std::cout << ad;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And to show the the advantage of the object oriented approach, I will modify the classes without the need to change the consumers / users of them.

Let's use 2 excplict double values in the first class ("AerodynamicsValues") and read only 2 values from a line, even if there are more. If there is some fault, we will set the values to 0. We also change the regex to only match double values. So, we do not look for a comma and ignore but we do now lokk explitely for patterns that match double values.

In the 2nd class ("Aerodynamics") we only change, that we will read 500 lines.

No need to change something somewhere else.

Function `main` is the same as before. And now you can add additional functions to the classes and there will be no need to change other parts of the code.

Please see the final C++ software

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// This makes sure that we read double only
const std::regex reForDouble{ R"((([+-]?(?:[[:d:]]+\.?|[[:d:]]*\.[[:d:]]+))(?:[Ee][+-]?[[:d:]]+)?))" };

constexpr size_t LinesToRead = 500U;

struct AerodynamicsValues {

    // Our internal data 
    double adv1{};
    double adv2{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, AerodynamicsValues& ad) {

        // Read one complete line
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {

            // Split string
            std::vector temp(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), reForDouble, 1), {});

            // if we have read at least 2 double values for this line
            if (temp.size() > 1U) {

                // Convert read strings to double
                ad.adv1 = stod(temp[0]);
                ad.adv2 = stod(temp[1]);
            }
            else {
                // If we could not read at leas 2 doubles, we will set the values to default 0
                ad.adv1 = ad.adv2 = {};
            }
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Overwrite inserter 
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const AerodynamicsValues& ad) {
        return os << ad.adv1 << ' ' << ad.adv2;
    }
};


struct Aerodynamics {

    // All Aerodynamics data
    std::vector<AerodynamicsValues> data{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Aerodynamics& ad) {
        // Read all data
        ad.data.clear();
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<AerodynamicsValues>(is), LinesToRead, std::back_inserter(ad.data));
        return is;
    }

    // Overwrite inserter 
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Aerodynamics& ad) {
        std::copy(ad.data.begin(), ad.data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<AerodynamicsValues>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream csvFile{ "r:\\Aerodynamics.csv" }; csvFile) {

        Aerodynamics ad{};

        // Read all values from CSV file
        csvFile >> ad;

        // Show read data to user
        std::cout << ad;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.

1. There are many other possible solutions for the problem
2. No, `std::sregex_token_iterator` is not too much. It is appropriate

Have fun . . .